# Get Product Image If The Status is Equal To 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This looks simple but got stuck. So let me share the table structure first:

**Products:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NULL,
[CategoryID] [int] NULL,
[ProductName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Details] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Price] [float] NULL,
[Stock] [float] NULL
)
```

**ProductImages:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductImages](
[ImageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NULL,
[ImageName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[ImageDetails] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Status] [int] NULL
)
```

The ProductID is the foreign key in the **ProductImages** table. So what I want is to show all the products with images whose Status = 1 (Status column in the **ProductImages** table). Now here is a logic. If I do INNER or LEFT JOIN both the tables, then it'll show the products that has status 1 with following query:

```
SELECT m.ProductID, m.CategoryID, m.ProductName, m.Details, m.Price,
m.Stock, k.ImageName, k.Status FROM Products m LEFT JOIN ProductImages k
ON k.ProductID = m.ProductID WHERE k.Status = 1
```

But my requirement is all the products will be shown with images by default like (No images available). Only the images from **ProductImages** table will be shown up when it's Status is 1. If Status = 0, then the product is shown but with no images text or whatever. Here is a sample output that I supposed to get:

[image: image_status]

**Note:** Only the images with status 1 will be shown else by default no images with product details.

Comment: Could you please attach sample data? I'm wondering which query is the output presented coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with your status column from both outputs, but if I understand you correctly this is a simple `CASE` expression showing `"No images"` string when `Status <> 1` (meaning the left join didn't find any images with `Status = 1`) else show the value from that column:

```
SELECT 
  m.ProductID, m.CategoryID, m.ProductName, m.Details, m.Price, m.Stock, 
  k.Status,
  CASE WHEN k.Status <> 1 THEN 'No images' ELSE k.ImageName END AS ImageName, 
FROM Products m 
LEFT JOIN ProductImages k
  ON k.ProductID = m.ProductID AND k.Status = 1
```

Comment: you got confused but seems like your query has done the job neatly. Thanks a lot. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case when status = 1 then show the column ImageName otherwise null

```
  SELECT 
      m.ProductID
    , m.CategoryID
    , m.ProductName
    , m.Details
    , m.Price
    , m.Stock
    , case k.status when 1 then k.ImageName else null end as imageName
    , k.Status 
    FROM Products m 
    LEFT JOIN ProductImages k
          ON k.ProductID = m.ProductID WHERE k.Status = 1
```